# The function or layer might be signed using a signature that the client is not configured to accept

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a Lambda with code signing using CDK. I define my resources like this:

```js
const signingProfile = new signer.SigningProfile(scope, 'MySigningProfile', {
  platform: signer.Platform.AWS_LAMBDA_SHA384_ECDSA,
  signingProfileName: 'MySigningProfile'
});

const codeSigningConfig = new lambda.CodeSigningConfig(scope, 'MyCodeSigningConfig', {
  signingProfiles: [signingProfile],
  untrustedArtifactOnDeployment: lambda.UntrustedArtifactOnDeployment.ENFORCE,
});

const myLambda = new NodejsFunction(scope, "MyLambda", {
  codeSigningConfig,
  functionName: "MyLambda",
  entry: "src/aws/my-lambda.ts",
  handler: "handler",
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
  timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
  memorySize: 2048,
});
```

than I build my stack with:

```
`cdk synth --output build/cdk.out`
```

and finally I deploy it using:

```
cd build
cdk deploy --app cdk.out
```

The first time I execute this process everything works fine, the Lambda gets deployed and I can see that it is using the code signing configuration on the AWS Console, but then if make any change to the code of my Lambda and try to deploy it again I get the following error:

> Resource handler returned message: "Lambda cannot deploy the function: - The function or layer might be signed using a signature that the client is not configured to accept. Check the provided signature for arn:aws:lambda:xx-xxxx-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:MyLambda

I came accross these two issues on GitHub, but I can't pinpoint any differences between what I am doing and their solutions:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2424
- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14489